# Sharepoint Authentication via REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, authentication, token, cookie

I would like to connect to Sharepoint via REST API and Javascript. Based on readings I've done, first you need to have Security Token, then you use this Security Token to get FedAuth cookies, afterwards you need FedAuth cookies to get Digest information which you will need to include in every request that you will make.

I am able to get the Security Token via connecting to URL `https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf`. However I'm stuck with getting the FedAuth cookies. From the resources I've checked you need to send request to "
`https://[yoursharepointsite].sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0`, however I get response like following

> [USER] does not have permissions to access this resource

Is there a missing set up on the User Account I am using or additional set up needed on the site?

Comment: Were you ever able to make progress on this @faaliwin?